# 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, webdeploy, azure-web-app-service

When I publish my app to a Azure Website I get the error on the title and nothing works. It's not temporary.

I researched and looks like it's not related to the problems people have that error have.

I enabled logging but haven't got a much significat otuput.

The log says:

> 2014-01-15 10:56:26 ~1MANDOOSYSTEM GET /diagnostics/settings
>   X-ARR-LOG-ID=5632dfdf-9cda-482a-a1d8-e0a9944c8e51 443 - 70.37.162.148
>   Azure-Portal/3.14.00298.7 - - mandoosystem.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0
>   0 463 939 1718

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, it ended up being a code error, that would cause a stack overflow if the connection string wasn't set correctly, which wasn't for the cloud.

I would expect to see a more meaningful error while in the cloud since I enabled all the logging features.

Not sure how this works but apparently the server itself was timing out and the other server, the gateway I believe, didn't have a clue on what was up. Just my assumption.

Comment: Any chance you could post what the code error was? "Not set correctly" is not very helpful.

Comment: You could connect via ftp and check the LogFiles in the root folder. There you have more details, that maybe you don't want to expose to your users/customers.