# How to configure EmailService class in IdentityConfig.cs to send email for password reset in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

I am developing an application in ASP.Net MVC, one of the requirements is reset password functionality, i cant figure out how to send password recovery email so a user can reset password.

Here is my code in the web config:

```
  <system.net>
  <mailSettings>
  <smtp from="from@gmail.com">
  <network host="smtp.gmail.com" defaultCredentials="false" password="password" port="587" enableSsl="true" />
  </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Here is my EmailService class in the IdentityConfig.cs:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        return client.SendMailAsync("email from web config",
                                    message.Destination,
                                    message.Subject,
                                    message.Body);

     }
  }
```

This doesn't send email, i don't know what might the problem, hope someone can help.

Comment: I have removed your password for you... You should change it now, though

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you're attempting to do somewhat like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674457/how-to-configure-sender-email-credentials-for-asp-net-identity-usermanager-sende), try using `async` and `await` keywords (since it's a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` method) and wrap `SmtpClient` inside `using` statement to manage `IDisposable` instance easier (see [this reference](https://blog.falafel.com/avoid-taskcanceledexception-sending-email-async/) if you encounter so-called `TaskCanceledException`):

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            await client.SendMailAsync("email from web config",
                                        message.Destination,
                                        message.Subject,
                                        message.Body);
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use `using` statement, `SmtpClient.SendCompleted` event must be handled to dispose `SmtpClient` instance manually after sending mail:

```
public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
{
    // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

    // Registering SendCompleted event and dispose SmtpClient after sending message
    client.SendCompleted += (s, e) => {
        client.Dispose();
    };

    return client.SendMailAsync("email from web config",
                                message.Destination,
                                message.Subject,
                                message.Body);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have implemented both your answer, but still no message is sent to email for password reset. I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Looking from the solution source it should be worked, have you getting exception or other errors before/after sending mail? Check if your mail account used for sending has bounced test mail.