# Get Mail Setting from Web.Config in SendAsync Method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, forgot-password, sendasync

I am working on Forgot Password Functionality. In my `web.config` file I have done the mail settings:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="email">
        <network host="host" port="25" userName="" password="=" enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

In my `SendAsync` method I am trying to read setting from `web.config`:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
return client.SendMailAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SupportEmailAddr"],
                                    message.Destination,
                                    message.Subject,
                                    message.Body);
```

I have no idea what is this: `AppSettings["SupportEmailAddr"]`

I took this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523276/usermanager-sendemailasync-no-email-sent).

It is giving me following exception:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.config file you have a section called: `<appSettings>`.

That is what `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` is referring too.

`["SupportEmailAddr"]` is looking at a specific setting called `SupportEmailAddr`.

In your web.config it would look something like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SupportEmailAddr" value="someone@example.com" />
</appSettings>
```

You are getting the value cannot be null message because you will not have the setting in your web.config as above.

So to fix the error message find your `<appSettings>` and add:

```
<add key="SupportEmailAddr" value="someone@example.com" />
```

Alternatively, if you have the current value in your AppSettings already then just change the key that you are looking for in the C# code.

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CorrectAppSettingKey"]
```

Note: if you plan on using any of the web.config inheritance features you should `WebConfiguratonManger.AppSettings` instead of `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`. See the difference between the two here: [What's the difference between the WebConfigurationManager and the ConfigurationManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698157/whats-the-difference-between-the-webconfigurationmanager-and-the-configurationm)

Comment: So I should add new key in my config file with SupportEmailAddr. Leave other setting as they are.

Comment: @MHussain Yes, unless you have the correct setting already there. If you already have a setting you want to use. Change `SupportEmailAddr` in `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SupportEmailAddr"]` to the key you want to use. e.g. `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyOtherKey"]`

Comment: I am getting reset email now. But when I am clicking on link getting following error: 
`A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (code="...QQ==">here</a")`

Comment: @MHussain Best to create a new question for that one :)

Comment: I found solution. My Bad.